# Move the rest of member of an Struct Array after sorting one of its members

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct, bubble-sort

I know there are way better and easier ways to do this, but for my class this is the only thing I can use and just work with what I have.

I am working on a Inventory Menu project, and I have to sort the "sku" number with a bubble sort, now my issue is that, **I don't know how to move the other members at the same time.**

Each sku number has its product's name, price and quantity. The code that I have sorts only the sku numbers and it works, the only thing is that the rest of the members stay in the same place.

*What can I do?*

**NOTE**: THE FUNCTION IS `sortArray`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;

struct inventory {

  string name;
  int sku;
  int quantity;
  double price;
};

int size = 0;

void fillArray ( inventory[], int&, ifstream& );
void sortArray ( inventory[], int );
void displayIn ( inventory[], int );
int lookupSku ( inventory[], int, int );
int lookupName ( inventory[], int, string );

int main(){
  // Constants for menu choices
  const int DISPLAY_INVENTORY = 1,
            LOOKUP_SKU = 2,
            LOOKUP_NAME = 3,
            QUIT_CHOICE = 4;

  // Variables
  int choice;

  inventory products [100];

  ifstream fin;
  fin.open ("inventory.dat");

  if (!fin)
  {
    cout << endl << endl
         << " ***Program Terminated. *** " << endl << endl
         << " Input file failed to open. " << endl;

    system ( "PAUSE>NUL" );

    return 1;
  }

  fillArray ( products, size, fin );
  sortArray ( products, size );

   // Set up numeric output formatting.
   cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

   do
   {
      // Display the menu.
      cout << "\n\t\t Manage Inventory Menu\n\n"
           << "1. Display inventory sorted by sku\n"
           << "2. Lookup a product by sku\n"
           << "3. Lookup a product by name\n"
           << "4. Quit the Program\n\n"
           << "Enter your choice: ";
      cin >> choice;
      cout << endl;

      // Validate the menu selection.
      while (choice < DISPLAY_INVENTORY || choice > QUIT_CHOICE)
      {
         cout << "Please enter a valid menu choice: ";
         cin >> choice;
      }

      // Validate and process the user's choice.
      if (choice != QUIT_CHOICE)
      {
         int indexSku,
             indexName,
             skuChoice;

         string nameChoice;

         switch (choice)
         {
            case DISPLAY_INVENTORY:
                displayIn ( products, size );
            break;

            case LOOKUP_SKU:
                cout << "Enter the Sku number: ";
                cin >> skuChoice;

                indexSku = lookupSku( products, size, skuChoice );

                cout << "Product Name: " << products[indexSku].name << endl
                     << "Sku: " << products[indexSku].sku << endl
                     << "Quantity: " << products[indexSku].quantity << endl
                     << "Price: " << products[indexSku].price << endl;
            break;

            case LOOKUP_NAME:
                cout << "Enter name of product with no spaces: ";
                cin >> nameChoice;
                cout << endl;

                indexName = lookupName ( products, size, nameChoice );

                cout << "Product Name: " << products[indexName].name << endl
                     << "Sku: " << products[indexName].sku << endl
                     << "Quantity: " << products[indexName].quantity << endl
                     << "Price: " << products[indexName].price << endl;
            break;
         }

      }
   } while (choice != QUIT_CHOICE);

 fin.close ();

 return 0; 
}

void fillArray ( inventory product[], int &size, ifstream &fin )
{
  int counter = 0;

  while (fin >> product[counter].name)
  {
     fin >>  product[counter].sku>> product[counter].quantity
         >> product[counter].price;

     counter ++;
  }

  size = counter;
}

void sortArray ( inventory product[], int size )
{
   bool swap;
   int temp;

   do
   {
      swap = false;
      for (int count = 0; count < (size - 1); count++)
      {
         if ( product[count].sku > product[count + 1].sku )
         {
            temp = product[count].sku;
            product[count].sku = product[count + 1].sku;
            product[count + 1].sku = temp;
            swap = true;
         }
      }
   } while (swap);
}


void displayIn ( inventory product[], int size )
{

  for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
  {
    cout << product[i].sku << "    " <<  product[i].quantity << "     "
         <<  product[i].price << "    " << setw(4) <<  product[i].name 
         <<endl;
  }
}

int lookupSku(inventory product[], int size, int value)
{
   int first = 0,
       last = size - 1,
       middle,
       position = -1;
   bool found = false;

   while (!found && first <= last)
   {
      middle = (first + last) / 2;
      if (product[middle].sku == value)
      {
         found = true;
         position = middle;
      }
      else if (product[middle].sku > value)
         last = middle - 1;
      else
         first = middle + 1;
   }
   return position;
}

int lookupName ( inventory product[], int size , string value )
{
   int first = 0,
       last = size - 1,
       middle,
       position = -1;
   bool found = false;

   while (!found && first <= last)
   {
      middle = (first + last) / 2;
      if (product[middle].name == value)
      {
         found = true;
         position = middle;
      }
      else if (product[middle].name > value)
         last = middle - 1;
      else
         first = middle + 1;
   }
   return position;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap the entire `struct`, not just the member `sku`.

```
    if ( product[count].sku > product[count + 1].sku )
     {
        inventory temp = product[count];
        product[count] = product[count + 1];
        product[count + 1] = temp;
        swap = true;
     }
```

Comment: Hii thank you! I tried it that way but it gives me an error: error cannot convert 'inventory' to 'int' in assignment and no match for operator = as operand types are 'inventory' and 'int'

Comment: @MariaFernanda, what kind of error are you getting? Compile time error? Run time error?

Comment: That's probably because you still have `int temp;`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to keep an array of pointers of inventory structs. Sort the elements on the same condition `product[count]->sku > product[count + 1]->sku`
but instead of swapping the sku values, swap the `product[count]` and `product[count+1]`. I hope it helps.
[You can see here how to initalize an array of pointers to struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nelt6.png)

source: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/13778/

Comment: Hi Ramzah, thanks for replying, I tried that but it gives me a couple of errors pretty much saying that it cannot compare a type 'inventory' (which is the struct} to and int